# como enviar key value por POST en PHP

Tags: php, curl, postman

cuando hago la consulta en Postman, pongo el valor de la llave 'producto' y su valor que quiero buscar, y ahorra resultados sin problemas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al hacerlo desde php no tengo resultado alguno.

```
public static function busquedaModel($input){
    $urlBase = Routesurl::CtrlRoutes();
    $url = $urlBase.'/api/busqueda';
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $payload = $input;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

no se que puede estar fallando, si me pueden dar una mano se los agradecería mucho.
saludos

Comment: Por lo que veo en la captura de Postman... ¿Haces la petición con el método POST, pero mandas los parámetros por headers?

Comment: asi es, esta mal? :(

Comment: Los parámetros deben enviarse en el body, no en los headers. Pero eso es problema del api que estás usando. Si no tienes forma de modificar el api o no es viable, se te puede ayudar a replicar la petición que hace Postman en tu captura. También sería bueno que editaras tu pregunta agregando el valor de la variable `$input` en tu código para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Entiendo, me gustaría saber por que mandarlo por el body y no por el header, el valor del $input = $_POST[] que viene de un buscador simple en html, gracias

Comment: gracias de nuevo, ya funciona, solo tuve que cambiar array('Content-Type:application/json')); por array('producto:'.$payload.''));, es producto por que es el header que acepta la api, gracias otra vez